# why function returns undefined when it should be 'n/a'?

Tags: javascript

> the problem have to be solved is:
>   You are given a string of numbers between 0-9. Find the average of these numbers and return it as a 
>   floored whole number (ie: no decimal places) written out as a string.
>   Eg:
>
> "zero nine five two" -> "four"
>
> If the string is empty or includes a number greater than 9, return
>   "n/a"
>   this is my solution so far:

```js
function averageString(str) {
    var thelast = [];
    var obj = {
        "zero": 0,
        "one": 1,
        "two": 2,
        "three": 3,
        "four": 4,
        "five": 5,
        "six": 6,
        "seven": 7,
        "eight": 8,
        "nine": 9
    }
    var sum = 0;
    var nums = []
    var string = str.split(" ");
    string.forEach(el => {
        nums.push(obj[`${el}`])
    })
    if (str == " ") {
        thelast.push("n/a")
    } else {

        nums.forEach(el => {
            if (el > 9) {
                thelast.push("n/a")
            } else {
                sum += el
            }

        })
        var final = Math.floor(sum / nums.length);

        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (obj[prop] == final) {
                thelast.push(prop)
            }

        }
    }
    return thelast[0]
}
console.log(averageString("one two ten four five"));
```

> but why it returns undefined when the solution should be 'n/a'?

Comment: How would your code generate an element that's > 9 ?

Comment: when the argument is "one two ten four five"

Comment: Are you sure? What is in the nums array if you give it "one two ten four five" ?

Comment: [1, 2, undefined, 4, 5]

Comment: You also have the 'empty string' check, which is `(str == " ")`. What if the string is completely empty `""`? I recommend properly validating the input before doing any computation: make sure that it contains at least one number, and that that number is zero-to-nine. If that check fails, return `"n/a"`; if it succeeds, perform the computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you only return `"n/a"` if the number, after looking it up, is greater than 9. But if you look up the value `"ten"`, it will return `undefined`, because you don't have a case for it. You can't add all values greater than 9, because there are infinitely many of them. (You also have a problem if `str` is empty `""`.)

What you need to do instead, is check if the value returned from the lookup `=== undefined`.

Better yet however, you could have a proper validation step, that checks the input that the function receives, before performing any calculation on it. You are already told what is valid input and what isn't, so you need code that returns `true` if the input is valid, and `false` if it is not. If the input is invalid, you return `"n/a"`, otherwise you calculate and return the average.

After splitting the validation out into its own function, I have taken the liberty of extracting other parts out into their own functions. The overall implementation method remains the same, but is perhaps simpler to follow.

I see that you are using [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), so I recommend looking into [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
function textToNum(str) {
  var numbers = {
      "zero": 0,
      "one": 1,
      "two": 2,
      "three": 3,
      "four": 4,
      "five": 5,
      "six": 6,
      "seven": 7,
      "eight": 8,
      "nine": 9
  };
  return numbers[str];
}

function numToText(str) {
  var numbers = [
    "zero",
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four",
    "five",
    "six",
    "seven",
    "eight",
    "nine"
  ];
  return numbers[str];
}

function validateInput(str) {
  var numbers = str.split(" ");
  return numbers.length > 0 && !numbers.some(num => textToNum(num) === undefined);
}

function averageString(str) {
  if (!validateInput(str)) {
    return "n/a";
  }
  // Now we know that the input is valid
  var sum = 0;
  var nums = [];
  var string = str.split(" ");
  string.forEach(el => {
    nums.push(textToNum(el));
  });
  nums.forEach(el => {
    sum += el;
  });
  var final = Math.floor(sum / nums.length);
  return numToText(final);
}

console.log(averageString("one two four five"));
console.log(averageString("one two ten four five"));
console.log(averageString("one two four five thirty"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you're testing for empty string you should be testing for `undefined`, since numbers larger than "nine" are not defined as keys in your `obj` variable.  The function can't give you numbers greater than 9 because you haven't defined them.  This also improves the function because it handles other random strings like "dog" or misspellings like "for"

`if (el === undefined) {
  thelast.push("n/a") 
}`

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code is handling anything greater than 9 with an undefined.  What you need to do is check to see if the value IS undefined, then proceed to push 'n/a' for that value within the loop like this:

```
string.forEach(el => {
     if (obj[`${el}`] === undefined){
        nums.push('n/a')
     } else{
        nums.push(obj[`${el}`])
     }
```

Now, your `nums` array will look like this:
`[ 1, 2, 'n/a', 4, 5 ]`

I would do the whole thing like so:

```
function averageString(str) {
  var thelast = [];
    var obj ={
    "zero": 0,
    "one": 1,
    "two": 2,
    "three": 3,
    "four": 4,
    "five": 5,
    "six": 6,
    "seven": 7,
    "eight": 8,
    "nine": 9
  }
   var sum = 0;
  var nums =[]
   var string = str.split(" ");
     string.forEach(el => {
     if (obj[`${el}`] === undefined){
        nums.push('n/a')
     } else{
        nums.push(obj[`${el}`])
     }
  })

nums.forEach(el => {
   if(el > 9){
        thelast.push("n/a") 
   }else{
        sum += el
   }
 })


if (nums.includes('n/a')){
    return 'n/a'
} else{
    var final = Math.floor(sum / nums.length);
    return final
}

}
```